# Forgot passphrase for new SSL certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate, keys

I've been requested by RapidSSL to reissue my SSL certificate to 2048 bits.
I generated a key, CSR and got the certificate back from RapidSSL.

Now, somehow, I've forgotten what Passphrase I used when generating the Key. Apache is asking for it, telling me "5 tries left". For the moment, I've reverted back to the old certificate.

What are my options here? Can I recreate a new key/CSR and generate a new certificate with RapidSSL? I don't see the option anymore to generate a new certificate. What happens when too many attempts to guess the key are put in?

Comment: Q: What are my options here? A: Find a better method of keeping track of critical passwords/passphrases, like the one for your SSL certificate.

Comment: I wont recommend to put pass phrase on certificate.You need to enter pass phrase each time when you restart the webserver.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to regenerate your SSL certificate with RapidSSL. They allow multiple signing changes as long as its the same domain.